# Is there _delay_ms() active waiting in SDCC+STM8 MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, stm8

Is there _delay_ms() active waiting function in SDCC for STM8 MCU?

(I only found delay100tcy() for pic16 in includes)
If it doesn't exist, what is the simplest implementation?
FCPU macro is known.

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from [here](https://github.com/Hoksmur/stm8_routines/blob/master/delay.h):

```
#define T_COUNT(x) (( F_CPU * x / 1000000UL )-5)/5)

static inline void _delay_cycl( unsigned short __ticks )
{
    __asm__("nop\n nop\n"); 
    do {    
      __ticks--;
    } while ( __ticks );
    __asm__("nop\n");

static inline void _delay_us( const unsigned short __us )
{
    _delay_cycl( (unsigned short)( T_COUNT(__us) );
}

static inline void _delay_ms( unsigned short __ms )
{
    while ( __ms-- )
    {
        _delay_us( 1000 );
    }
}
```